# Excluding Java test files from SonarQube 4.1.1 analysis

Tags: java, junit, sonarqube

I do not wand violations to be reported for Java test files in SonarQube, but I do want JUnit and Cobertura code coverage to be analyzed and displayed (JUnit and code coverage reports are reused, not executed by SonarQube).

How do I exclude test files from violations analysis only? I tried adding to global exclusion these settings, but they are not working:

```
**/test/**
**/Test*.*
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to use the `sonar.exclusions` property?

Comment: yes I added the above to sonar.exclusions property but I didn't see it work. I also tried the test exclusions property, and it worked, but it also removed my JUnit test results, which is not acceptable.

Comment: Right, this is the intended behaviour. I think that the solution would be to use the `Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria` http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus

Comment: Glad, I could help. I've added the comment as answer as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SonarQube can ignore issues on certain components and against certain coding rules. You might want to read the `Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria` section in [SonarQube Narrowing the Focus](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus).

As mentioned in the documentation:

> You can ignore issues on certain components and for certain coding rules.
>
> Examples:
>
> - I want to ignore all issues on all files => *;**/*
> - I want to ignore all issues on COBOL program bank/ZTR00021.cbl => *;bank/ZTR00021.cbl
> - I want to ignore all issues on classes located directly in the Java package com.foo, but not in its sub-packages => *;com/foo/*
> - I want to ignore all issues against coding rule cpp.Union on files in the directory object and its sub-directories => cpp.Union;object/**/*